# A possible characterization of divisible modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

According to [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisibleModule.html):

> **Definition.** Let $R$ denote a commutative ring and $M$ denote a module over $R$. Then $M$ is *divisible* iff for every $a \in R$, if $a$ is not a zero-divisor, then for all $x \in M$, we have that "$x$ can be divided by $a$" (meaning that there exists $x' \in M$ such that $x = ax'$.)

Clearly, we can deduce that $M$ is divisible from the statement that $M$ can be made into a module over $\mathrm{tqr}(R)$ (the total quotient ring of $R$); just take $x'$ as $a^{-1}x,$ and we're done.

I can't quite tell whether or not the converse holds:

> **Question.** Assuming the axiom of choice, is it true that for all rings $R$ and all modules $M$ over $R$, if $M$ is a divisible module, then $M$ can be made into a module over $\mathrm{tqr}(R)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and the axiom of choice is irrelevant. For example, take $R = \mathbb{Z}, M = \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. $M$ is a divisible $R$-module but cannot be made into a module over the fraction field $\mathbb{Q}$: modules over $\mathbb{Q}$ correspond to *uniquely* divisible abelian groups.